# How to make this nested query :-

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I've a table called `foo` which stores the child and parent information of some entity called `bar`, with level information as well. If there is no parent of `bar`, then in the `parent_id` column it will store its own id.

```
id  parent_id 
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   2
6   4
```

So in my example, the bar entities with an id of 1 and 2 are at level 0 (no parent) and have children. The bar with an id of 4 has a child but it also has a parent, so its not at level 0.

I am trying to write a mysql query which will return all the bars that have children and are at level 0 (no parent).

I am able to write the query below, which shows the `bars` that have children:

```
select * from foo where id!=parent_id;
```

And output of above query is :

```
id parent_id
4   1
5   2
6   4
```

But in above query, parent_id 4 is not at level 0 and I need a query that produces the output below:

```
id parent_id
1   1
2   2
```

Let me know if you need any additional information from my side.

Edit :- Thanks Evan for pointing out my mistake, actually I want ids "that have children and are at level 0". Also I've updated the correct O/P.

Comment: *"I am trying to write a mysql query which will return all the bars that have children and are at level 0 (no parent)."* You mean that have children and are **NOT** at level 0?

Comment: @EvanCarroll , I mean that have children and are at level 0.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... *"bar entities with an id of 1 and 2 are at level 0 (no parent) and have children"* So why aren't you returning 1, and 2.

Comment: @EvanCarroll , sorry my bad, thanks for your insightful comment. i'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add to the where statement to filter for those that are the primary level

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo AS f1
WHERE id = parent_id
AND id IN (
  SELECT f2.parent_id
  FROM foo AS f2
  WHERE f1.id = f2.parent_id
    AND f2.id != f2.parent_id
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i just updated my question, your query will return "that have children and are NOT at level 0". But i want result which have "that have children and are at level 0".

Comment: I think you want `id=parent_id` read the comments on the question

Comment: @EvanCarroll, I've updated the question.

Comment: I went ahead and updated this feel free to roll back that update. The OP changed the question. His data and description was inaccurate.

Comment: @EvanCarroll , thanks for the answer, but its returning 3 as well. which doesn't have any child.

Comment: final query will be `select * from message2 as m1 where id=parent_id and parent_id in (select m2.parent_id from message2 as m2 where m2.id != m2.parent_id)` ;

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal don't think so, try my query. Updated again.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, i just tried my query and getting the expected O/P. but let me try your query as well. Also why you think that my query wont work ?

Comment: @EvanCarroll , your query is giving the same O/P as mine.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Yours is selecting all children, not just children of level 0. That's slower and more memory intensive. And, it's assuming level 0 is designated by id = parent_id. parent_id of level 0 should really be null. You should fix that.

Comment: @EvanCarroll , thanks for giving the insights on performance, i'll definitely use the one given by you. Also i know parent_id should be null, but its by design and can't change it now.